# dynamic height of custom view with Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Actually I am implementing a custom info window in Google Map,
I add it with this lines:

```
    //MARK: GMSMapViewDelegate
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {
    let infoView : SpMapInfoWindowView = SpMapInfoWindowView.loadFromNibNamed("SpMapInfoWindowView") as! SpMapInfoWindowView;
    infoView.lblLocationName.text = LONG_TEXT;
    return infoView;
}
```

And my xib layout setting is as following:
[image: UI structure]
Auto layout part:
[image: constraints of the label]

I want the infowindow's height would increase if the text becomes longer.
I've tried a lot with the constraints' priority but the UILabel's height fail to be changed.

What do I miss?

### Edited 2015-07-02

After trying lots of priority and compression resistance, the label would resize but not the superview

Comment: Have you tried to set required vertical compression resistance for a label? Also align center Y is unnecessary since you already have top and bottom constraints

Comment: for this you need to calculate the size of text of your lable, and based on the calculated size, you need to change the frame of your customView and then call layoutIfNeeded on your customView, that's it.

Comment: @HitendraHckr, I am not going to do it by programming, I think autolayout would handle it if I set it correctly. It works fine with cell's height.

Comment: @Sega-Zero, I haven't tried it, I would edit the question once I tried it.

Comment: try  remove height constrain and set number of line should zero

Comment: @GauravPatel, removed but no help. numberOfLine won't affect the result as the label successfully grow as expected. The problem is how to make the superview grow with it. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

set `numberOfLines` of your uilabel to 0. (in IB - 'Lines' property)

Also, try to calculate height of your label programmatically

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
label.font = font
label.text = text

label.sizeToFit()
```

And  then  set size of your container as `label.frame.height + your_margins`

Comment: Changing the control height just to determine it's size is a very bad way. It's better to use `sizeThatFits:` or `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:`. Also there's no need in doing it programmatically, the view can adopt a label's height automatically, that's what autolayout is intended for.

Comment: I agree with @Sega-Zero, that's why I am asking how to do it with autolayout.